# changing color of <md-toolbar>?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

This is how my code looks like on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/harit/pen/KdxJzJ):

I want the background of "`Sidenav Left`" to be that of "`Menu Items`", which is represented by class as

```
.nav-theme {
  background-color: #34495E
}
```

I tried overriding it as

```
.nav-theme, .md-theme-indigo {
  background-color: #34495E
}
```

but that did not work, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 4):

Be more specific in your CSS selection to override. Since the below selectors are more specific, their priority will be higher than the default background color that was not getting overridden before. In this way you are avoiding the usage of `!important`

```
.md-sidenav-left .md-theme-indigo, .md-sidenav-left .nav-theme {
    background-color: #34495e;
}
```

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGLobO)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **[md-colors](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.6/api/directive/mdColors)** directive to set it to a color from your color palette. That way it'll change automatically if you pick a different theme.

```
<md-toolbar md-colors="::{background: '{{theme}}-primary-700'}"
```

Comment: `backgroundColor` is not working, to make it work use `<md-toolbar md-colors="::{background: '{{theme}}-primary-700'}"`

Comment: @Jouke, I could have sworn that I used it as I posted, but I see the documentation shows it as you have it. I'll update the answer.